# How do I make my method description scrollable?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio

I want to put a nice description for my method and I decided to do it like this.
But how do I make it so I can scroll through my parameters?
I want to get those arrows in intellisense so I can scroll through the different parameters

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to give a player x amount of x item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">A online players username.</param>
    /// <param name="item">the item ID.</param>
    /// <param name="amount">How much of this item would you like to give the player?</param>
    public void GiveItem(string user, int item, int amount)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are misunderstanding the work of *those arrows* You can see the arrows when a method has one or more overloads and you can see the different list of parameters expected by different overloads. In case of single method without overloads you can scroll between the list of parameters when you type the comma that separate one parameter from the next one

To see the arrows generated by intellisense try to add a second GiveItem
(this is just an example)

```
 public void GiveItem(string user, int item, int amount, int age)
 {
     ......
 }
```

Comment: I am not quite following along, so the arrows will only show if I have 2 instances of the GiveItem method?

Comment: The arrows are used to show you the different possible calls to the method with the same name, the commas are used to show the description of the parameter that is expected in a certain order for your call. Just type the first parameter value and then type a comma. Pressing CTRl+SPACE should show you the description of the second parameter

Comment: Of course when you type the open parentesys in GiveItem( you will see the description of the first parameter, when you type the comma after the first parameter you will see the description of the second parameter ...GiveItem("Jordan",

Comment: Ahh that makes sense!
Thanks for the great answer Steve!